# To group of array of objects by its id value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a group of array of objects in which that object property has value with ID number. I am successfully group it with that ID, however I am doing it by hardcode, not dynamically.

```
          var objBuyUser = response.newIdUserPul[i].arrayUserHistoryBuy;


          for (var y = 0; y < objBuyUser.length; y++) {
            if(objBuyUser[y].product_id == 1) {
              var doesIdExist = vm.pulBms.filter(function(v) {
                  return v.userid === response.newIdUserPul[i].id;
              });
              if(doesIdExist.length > 0) {
                //do nothhing
              } else {
                vm.pulBms.push({
                    userid:response.newIdUserPul[i].id,
                    buyAct: objBuyUser
                });
              }
            }
```

`objBuyUser[y].product_id == 1` is what will different them each other. As long as this time we only have three ID number 1, 2, 3, I just copied the same code by changing the id manually. So, anybody can help to make it dynamically?

(**)SO: actually we have the list of product: 1, 2, 3

In the backend, I have process a unique user with its history buy, assign by `response.newIdUserPul[i].` And the `arrayUserHistoryBuy` is the array of object detailing their product history buying from the range of the date, which in the object can consiste the date, quantity, and the product_id which need to be group here (reffer to -> **). In this case, knowing that each user can buy different product in the range of date, we still group it by product since the product is exist in the history of buying.

So the output could be similar like this:

```
ProductID1 : 
  {
    User: 123
    ProductBuyHistory : 
    {
      Date: 3-10-10
      ProductID : 2,
      Quantity: 10
    },
    {
      Date: 4-10-10
      ProductID : 1,
      Quantity: 10
    },
  }, 
  {
    User: 124
    ProductBuyHistory : 
    {
      Date: 3-10-10
      ProductID : 3,
      Quantity: 10
    },
    {
      Date: 4-10-10
      ProductID : 1,
      Quantity: 10
    },
  },
```

SO on for productId 2 and 3

Comment: Use `lodash`: `_.groupBy(objBuyUser, 'product_id')`, results in `{'1':[item1, item2], '2':[item3]}`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Don't recommend to use external libraries if it is not needed. This can be simply done in JS

Comment: What is the input array and what should be the final output ?

Comment: @Weedoze, I update the question, please.